# The Taylor coefficients of $\frac{1}{x \log(x)}$ are the harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

In the Analytic Combinatorics 4ed on page 160 the authors claim that the Taylor coefficients of $\frac{1}{x \log(x)}$ are the harmonic numbers. However, I do not understand why this is the case. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: What are “the Taylor coefficients of $\frac1{x\log(x)}$”?

Comment: Taylor expansion at what point $a$? I guess it is not $a=0$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\frac{-\log x}{x}$? The taylor expansion at $x=1$ is $-(x-1)+ \frac{3}{2} (x-1)^2 - \frac{11}{6} (x-1)^3 + \ldots$, whose coefficients are (up to sign) the harmonic numbers. This is normally presented as $\frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x}$, which is a well known generating function for the harmonic series.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: Thanks a lot!!! I misread it slightly, that solved it.